# Recursively list full absolute path of files with permissions in Linux

Tags: linux, grep, ls

I have done a bit of searching online, and I am trying to find a way to recursively list all files with their absolute path and with their permissions.  I want to do this so that I can `grep` out what I want, so that when I run the command, I can get just the matching files, their permissions, and their full paths, like:

```
<search command> | grep file.name
```

Output:

```
/home/current/Desktop/file.name
/etc/program/src/file.name
```

I would prefer to use `ls` because it is the fastest, and I would type:

```
ls -alR $PWD/
```

But this doesn't show the file's path, so if I `grep`'ed the output, then I would see file permissions, but not the directory from which it originated.

I can use `ls` integrated with `find` and `grep` to get the output in exactly the format that I want, and I could use something like this:

```
ls -ault `find $PWD/ -type f` | grep file.name
```

But this is extremely slow, I'm guessing because two commands are actually running.

If I just use `find` without `ls` or `grep`, then it goes faster, but it is a bunch to type:

```
find $PWD/ -type f -name file.name -printf '%M %u %g %s\t%a\t%p\r\n'
```

This will give me a nice format (It also includes the user, group, size, and last date of access, which are helpful).  However, it is a *ton* to type, and it is certainly not as fast as using `ls` with `grep`.

Is there a faster way to do what I am trying to do than to use `find`?

Comment: if your $PWD is huge, there is no faster way than your last `find` command. btw, you may want to have a `-a` (and) between -type and -name? or maybe single `-name` is enough for your find?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than `ls` or `find` you may try `tree`. Specifically `tree -ifpugDs $PWD` should give you what you would like.

`-if` removes indentation lines and prints out path

`-p` prints permissions

`-ug` prints user and group

`-D` prints modification time

`-s` prints size

Comment: Excellent, this appears to be exactly what I am trying to do.  It is just as fast as <code>ls</code>, and I can use <code>grep</code> to just show the lines that I am trying to show.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

If typing it is a problem, what about putting what you already have in a function:

```
myspecialfinder() {
  find $PWD/ -type f -name "$1" -printf '%M %u %g %s\t%a\t%p\r\n'
}
```

You would use it as

```
myspecialfinder file.name
```

Comment: This is good to keep in mind - I can put this in my .bashrc file so that every time I log on, I already have this function available.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -al`

Answer (score 0):

```
--tree -ifpugDs $PWD-- etc.
```

Very close.  The problem is `$PWD`, which results in useless
garbage if you have actual file names, not Unix-style file
names, that is, with no spaces.  To get it to work on any
file system, EG NTFS, you need to quote the $PWD.

I use the C-shell, as I was a berkeley/Sun user at the Lab, but the same ideas apply in bash.

```
tree -if "$PWD"
```

Now if your file name is

```
/home/he/Documents/00 - Writing/02 The Rapture of the Maiden/0 - Text/25th/Rapture, pt 1-4, ch 01-20 old.txt,
```

it doesn't crap out as soon as it hits the space.

I'm a big fan of English language file names, that is, not something like RSFunc97Stat.txt.  Maybe because, unlike most programmers, I can type with ten figures at a normal writing speed -- few people need more than 40 words per minute to type as fast as they can compose.  Most techies I've worked with use the 3-fingers-on-one-hand-2-on-the-other method, and they like to use short variable name, don't like to comment, and in general cannot be counted on to help with the user doc.  Also, it's an old habit from the days when you only got 8 chars to say it.

Nowadays, we need to support all file names, even "O'Reilly's Army.txt". I even have a database test item in all databases I made, called the "O'Reilly" test.  Many a program failed utterly when a text field had a quote mark or a leading pace, etc.  The good news is that tcsh autocompletes your files, and quotes them according to the correct archanesyntax.

Answer (score 0):

`find <path> -ls` does the trick. I was looking for the same thing, but didn't have `tree` installed.

Comment: What is the -ls argument for? When I look at the help output for find, I don't even seen those arguments listed.

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/1/find - list current file in ls -dils format on standard output

Comment: Thanks, it must not be a feature on all versions of 'find' that are out there. But I found the following to be a helpful explanation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169615/what-does-ls-do-when-used-with-find